# How to use FL Studio or Ableton to perform a set from a portfolio of songs?

Tags: synthesizer, ableton-live, fl-studio

I am trying to use FL studio to layer multiple sounds and effects to be used with a midi keyboard as a controller for a live set.  We usually do four songs per set once a week out of a portfolio.  Right now I am using the sounds built into my Yamaha S90 ES keyboard, but I'd like to start utilizing software controlled synths for the additional control and workflow.

The way I utilize the keyboard is to prepare a "performance" preset for each song where I can layer in multiple sounds and effects.  I then set those up so at the touch of a button I move to the next preset between songs.

I would like to do something similar with FL studio or other appropriate software.  Right now I'm able to get it set up for a single song easily by layering multiple plugins/sounds into the channel rack.  However, I'd like to be able to put that song's settings on the shelf so to speak to be able to use later when the song is pulled from the portfolio again.

I need a way to instantly switch between the sounds I have layered for one song, to the next in a set during a live performance. How can I accomplish this in FL Studio?

Comment: Are you using FL In Live mode? Simply save a song then open it later?

Comment: I haven't tried live mode. Right now I just have one project per song, with the channel rack and mixer set up for that song. It looks like I'll have to open each project between songs? Unless there is a good way to combine songs for a set, and switch between them.

Comment: Seems that live perfmance is a type of audio production. Also, the question is tied into some of the popular tags on this exchange, and there is a live perfmance tag. If you have a more appropriate forum, that would actually be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you can merge a few, say four, songs in a single project. Split all the mixer channels evenly (or not) among them, for instance, channels 1-16 belong to song one, channels 17-32 to song two and so forth; it makes sense to pick a song-local master in each group, say channel 1 is a master for song 1, so channels 2 through 16 are routed into it, and it itself is routed to the global master, and consequently in other groups/songs. Likewise, patterns are split into domains, say, patterns 1-50 for the first song, 51 to 100 for the second and so forth; they are strictly separated in time and space, so the first four minutes of transport belong to the song one, song two starts at 4:00 and goes through 9:00, etc. At the start of each song there's a special pattern that resets all controls (tempo, master volume and others) to appropritate levels—still care should be taken to not mess with shared resources—and mute all the irrelevant mixer channels/turn on relevant ones...

This can probably even be scripted, FL projects are zipped XML files after all.